# How to generate a CSR (certificate signing request) for creating a limited CA (Certificate Authority) using LibreSSL?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl

Related to this (too broad) question: [How to implement my PKI?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/231621/127025)

I have a self-signed CA (`ca0`)

I would like to create a CA (`ca1`) with limited power derived from that first CA.
`ca1` should only be able to sign certificates for `*.foo.com` and for `foo.com`.

From [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/31376/127025), I found out that the `Name Constraints` extension is probably what I want.

The key for `ca1` already exists and is `ca1.foo.key.pem`.

I already have an incomplete command for creating the request:

```
libressl req -new -sha512 -key ca1.foo.key.pem -out ca1.foo.csr.pem
```

What should I add to that line to limit ca1's power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the [NameConstraints extension](https://man.openbsd.org/x509v3.cnf.5#Name_constraints) to the request using LibreSSL's config file.  The following example is an extract - you'll need to add the various sections to your current config file and tweak the constraints:

```
[ req ]

# Don't prompt for the DN, use configured values instead
# This saves having to type in your DN each time.

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default
distinguished_name = req_dn

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 4096

# The extensions added when generating a CSR
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_dn ]

countryName            = GB
stateOrProvinceName    = Somewhere
organizationName       = Example
organizationalUnitName = PKI
commonName             = Example CA

[ req_ext ]

# Extensions added to the request

subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

basicConstraints            = critical, CA:TRUE
# basicConstraints          = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:1

keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign

# Policies and constraints are not recommended for Root CAs
# But could be enforced on subordinate CAs

nameConstraints        = @name_constraints

#policyConstraints = requireExplicitPolicy:1

#inhibitAnyPolicy = 1

#certificatePolicies = @CertPol

[ name_constraints ]
permitted;DNS.1 = example.org
permitted;DNS.2 = example.com
permitted;dirName.1 = style_1
permitted;dirName.2 = style_2

[ style_1 ]
C=gb
ST=somewhere
O=example
1.OU=head office
2.OU=admin

[ style_2 ]
1.DC=org
2.DC=example

[ CertPol ]
policyIdentifier = 1.3.6.1.4.132473
CPS = http://pki.example.org/cps.html
```

If you're not using the default configuration file you'll need to add `-config <config file>` to your command line.

**Note:** I've not tried this on LibreSSL - only on OpenSSL but I believe both use the same syntax.

Comment: Where are number.field (`1.OU`, `1.DC`), and the `DC` field documented?  I haven't found that documentation anywhere.

Comment: The numbering in that man page goes after the field, not before.  Is it the same?

Comment: I'm guessing that ``n.DC`` is the domain levels. Am I right?  For example for foo.bar.org it would be ``1.DC=org`` ``2.DC=bar`` ``3.DC=foo``.  If not, what is DC exactly for?

Comment: I tried ``openssl req -new -sha512 -key ca1.key.pem -out ca1.csr.pem`` (I edited ``/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`` directly) and got:

Comment: ``Error Loading request extension section req_ext
140424884049152:error:0D06407A:asn1 encoding routines:a2d_ASN1_OBJECT:first num too large:../crypto/asn1/a_object.c:73:
140424884049152:error:0B083077:x509 certificate routines:X509_NAME_ENTRY_create_by_txt:invalid field name:../crypto/x509/x509name.c:251:name=string_mask
140424884049152:error:220A4095:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:dirname error:../crypto/x509v3/v3_alt.c:481:
140424884049152:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:../crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:47:name=nameConstraints, value=@name_constraints``

Comment: I guess I will also have to copy the [ v3_ca ] contents of the default openssl.cnf into [ req_ext ], won't I? And if so, should I uncomment any of the commented lines?

Comment: You're correct re the DC elements. I've added a full example that should work with a few tweaks.