# Support for domain-specific root CAs in X.509 certificate format, OS and browsers

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Chance is one gets an invalid certificate warning when one follows this link https://www.cnss.gov. As explained [there](https://www.cnss.gov/CNSS/help/DoD_Root_Cert_Help_Final.pdf) (same warning) this is on purpose, and the solution is supposed to be to install<sup>1</sup> extra root Certification Authority certificate(s) in the machine or browser.

Is there support in the X.509 certificate format (e.g. some attribute) to

1. Restrict the rights of a CA accredited by a root CA certificate, and the CAs it may certify, to certifying for iad.gov, ioss.gov, cnss.gov domains? Without this (and support in OS or browsers), by installing a root CA certificate, one is granting unnecessary powers to the added root CA<sup>2</sup>.

   *Update*: a comment points to a question [*Can I restrict a Certification Authority to signing certain domains only?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/31376/6211), which answers tell that "Name Constraints" do just that. So make my question: how widely and correctly supported are "Name Constraints" by now<sup>3</sup>?
2. Make a root CA the exclusive supplier of certificates for stated domains? Without this (and support in OS or browsers), the domain-specific CA gives no protection that I can discern to the domain users, and the whole mess would seem pointless to me.

Note: I used "browsers" but the question extends to any program using certificates other than thru OS services.

---

<sup>1</sup> That's by running a 29MB executable that anyone can download (from a domain with standard CA practices), or installing a separate certificate which access appears restricted, but the question is *not* about how nonsensical these installation processes are.

<sup>2</sup> Admittedly, that may not be much of an issue, compared to the fact that many state actors of many states can obtain a rogue certificate for anything: there are already so many trusted CAs (counting those indirectly trusted), and it's enough to subvert one. IMHO, the complexity of actually organizing a Man-in-the-Middle attack, more than the residual risk of the rogue certificate being noticed, is the main deterrent against too casual a use of that facility. But the question is *not* about that either.

<sup>3</sup> And as a test: are the certificates we are asked to install in my example using "Name Constraints"?

Comment: Related:  [Can I restrict a Certification Authority to signing certain domains only?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/can-i-restrict-a-certification-authority-to-signing-certain-domains-only). But the newest answer there is 7 year old, another one 10 years old. So these might no reflect the current state.